# What is the max number of self-segregating words of length n?

Tags: formal-languages

A set of words **S** is called **self-segregating** if you don't need whitespaces to read them. It means that for any two words from **S** no new words from **S** arise between them.

For example the set **ab, bc, ac, ca** is not  self-segregating because **ca** is formed between **bc** and **ab**

Given an alphabet of **N** letters what is the maximum possible size of a self-segregating set of words of length **n**?

For two-lettered words, i.e. n=2, it's easy to prove that the answer is the floor of ${N^2}/{3}$.

But for n>2 the problem seems very difficult. I cannot solve it even for n=3.

Comment: Does it count if it takes three or more words to make another? (You refer only to two.) For example, if we have words ab, bc, cd, abbcc, then we can make the final word as a subword of the first three concatenated. But also, in your example, since all words have length two, any conjunction of those words is uniquely parsable, since we just take first two letters, next two, etc. In this sense, you don't need whitespace to read them. So I am confused about the precise definition of self-segregating.

Comment: It's about n-lettered  words. And it's all about what is between 2 adjacent words.

Comment: Could you state more precisely what it means to be self-segregating? After all, I don't need whitespace to parse words uniquely when they all have the same number of letters, so what you've written doesn't seem to be what you mean. I guess you mean that if $s$ and $t$ are words in the set, then $st$ has no other connected subword from the set.

Comment: But what if we don't know where the beginning is? My first definition is informal, but the second one is correct.

Comment: I guess you mean that if s
 and t
 are words in the set, then st
 has no other connected subword from the set. Yes. This is what I meant.

Comment: I guess that the reason that this problem is not well-known is that fixed-length codes are always decodable.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4877474/14578